# How to use vb.net to update MSAccess Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to write a method to accept a query as a parameter and then run that query to either add in a row into or edit the data in my database. I am using MS Access DB, Visual Studio to write my code, and VB.net as a coding language. I used a method that worked to query data from the database and modified it to modify data in the database. That is where things aren't quite working. Here is the code that I modified:

This is the query that i am passing into the method

```
query = "INSERT INTO TABLE ([Column 1], [Column 2]) VALUES ([GOTIT], 121212)"
```

This is the method that i am trying to get working

```
Public Sub ExecEditQuery(Query As String)
    'reset variables
    Exception = ""

    Try
        'open a connection (already declared as private variable: Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                                    ' "Data Source=Database.mdb;"))
        DBCon.Open()

        'create DB command
        DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

        'execute command
        DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    'close DB connection
    If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
```

Comment: GOTIT needs to be in quotes, not a bracket.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  I would kill this method since it doesn't seem capable of handling parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to a database, you need to dim the following variables:

```
Public Filename As String = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}YourDatabase.accdb"
Public ConStr As String = $"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA Source = {Filename}"
Public DBCon As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
```

Remember if you are inputting a string, remember to wrap it in quotation marks.
Also, if you are inputting in a table or field that is reserved by SQL for something else, it in back ticks (`)

For example:

```
DBCon.Open()

DBCmd = New OleDbCommand($"INSERT INTO `User` (Username) VALUES ('{Username}')", DBCon)

DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

With respect to your query, try rewriting as

```
query = $"INSERT INTO TABLE ([Column 1], [Column 2]) VALUES ('{GOTIT}', 121212)"
```